# Pasar un cursor que se llenó en el MainActivity a un fragment dentro de ese MainActivity - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, excepciones

Tengo un problema con un proyecto que estoy haciendo, se trata de un reproductor de música, mi problema es que realizo una búsqueda de los archivos de audio, la memoria externa, lleno el cursor en un método llamado repertorio que retorna el cursor para así pasarlo desde *MainActivity* a mi fragmento `fr_canciones` (*Fragment*).

Verifico que se llene correctamente, llamo al método `repertorio` del *MainActivity*, y lo asigno a un cursor creado en mi `fr_fragment`, pero me daba el error `NullPointerException` ya que llega el cursor vació, así que utilicé un `try/catch` para obtener el error y la aplicación corriera si se presentaban problemas con esto y tambien pensaba que con eso se resolvería.

He intentado de tres formas diferentes, pasar ese cursor a mi fragmento:

1. Con la instancia de *MainActivity* para llamar al método que retorna el cursor lleno.
2. Por medio del *bundle* para pasar dicho cursor como parámetro desde el *MainActivity* al fragmento.
3. Por medio de una clase aparte con obtentores y asignadores.

Pero ninguna de estas me ha funcionado.

Mi código es el siguiente:

MainActivity:

```
public final Cursor repertorio(){
    Cursor cursor = null;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
    };
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

fr_canciones:

```
ipublic class fr_canciones extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
Cursor cursor;
Biblioteca biblioteca = new Biblioteca();
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
int count;
TextView textView;

public fr_canciones() {
    //Asignacion por medio de metodo del main activity
    try {               
        cursor = mainActivity.repertorio();
        count = cursor.getCount();
    }catch (NullPointerException  e){
        Log.d("Error","Error");
    }
}
```

Lo estoy haciendo con *Fragments* porque tengo entendido que es una buena práctica utilizarlos, aunque tal ves seria mucho mas fácil con *Activities*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el problema es únicamente el contexto para poder llamar sin problema `getContentResolver()`, sugiero agregues como párametro el contexto a tu método:

```
public final Cursor repertorio(Context context){
    Cursor cursor = null;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
    };

    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

entonces al llamarlo desde el fragmento envia el contexto adecuado.

```
 ...
 cursor = mainActivity.repertorio(getActivity());
 ...
```